Importing Geopandas Receiving dlopen error
I'm attempting to import geopandas but receiving an error. I'm using and ArcGIS Pro conda environment and installed geopandas through conda. I do not have pygeos installed and would prefer to use Shapely.

I've attempted several reinstalls of geopanda using conda in multiple different environments. I keep on receiving the same error.

Try installing pygeos
